# Cross database association in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to make association between two cross database. but i have not any solution for this. So any one know then provide help me.

```
account_user.belongsTo(models.medical_country, { foreignKey:'country_id', targetKey: 'name'} );
account_user.hasMany(models.account_user_sharing, { foreignKey:'shared_by', as:'sharedBy'} );
account_user.hasMany(models.device_security, {foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'securitySettings'});
account_user.hasMany(models.account_doctorpatient, {foreignKey: 'doctor_id', as:'flag'});
account_user.belongsTo(models.account_pharmacist, {foreignKey: 'pharmacist_id', as: 'pharmacist'});
account_user.hasMany(models.user_notification, {foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'notification'});
```

Comment: Improved formatting